# How do you crop a specific area with paperclip in Rails (3)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip, crop

I have paperclip in Rails (3) working with simple cropping, for example the blow code makes a simple crop of the thumbnail:

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :thumb => "90x90#" }, :default_style => :thumb
```

However I was wondering how do you crop a very specific area of an image; lets say you have an x and y coordinate to start from and then a width and height of the crop.

How do you go about passing a complex style like this in?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check `{size}{offset}` combination here:

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry

Example where numbers are width, height, x, y:

```
90x90+40+30
```

Paperclip parses the style options string and it is limited to resizing and cropping. Complex ImageMagick options work if they are being passed as `:convert_options`, because they are added to `convert` command without modification.

```
has_attached_file :image,
  :styles => { :thumb => "" },
  :convert_options => { :thumb => "-crop 90x90+40+30" },
  :default_style => :thumb
```

Links to thumbnail processor source code and wiki page:

- https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/thumbnail.rb
- https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation

Comment: That just changes the size, it doesn't sample the x and y.

Comment: This is a far more elegant solution that the one with more votes. This is the way to do it.

Comment: To crop from the center:
`:thumb => "-gravity center -crop 90x90+0+0"`

Answer (score 4):

This could also answer your question:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images